# Join two tables on a field contais other field

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, join

How to join two tables if a field contains other field? Example:

On table A I have a field with data `'000;111;222'` and on table B I have a field with data `'111'`.

I want to join like this:

```
select * from A join B on A.field contains B.field
```

Comment: This is an obvous faq that is not researched & not useful. [ask] [help]

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a 
inner join b on b.field = any(string_to_array(a.field, ';'))
```

The join condition turns `a.field` to an array, then checks if it contains `b.field`.

Comment: function `string_to_array` not exists

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo: it does, as you can see in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) - that is, if you are running Postgres, that you tagged your question with.

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo: if the function string_to_array does not exist, you are not using Postgres

Comment: function string_to_array(record, unknown) not exists. the first field is a junction of two fields `(field_a, ';', field_b) as field_1` and the second field is a integer

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo Your second column can't be an integer because in your question you wrote: "*I have a field with data 'BBB'*" -  you can't have `'BBB'` in an integer column.

Answer (score 1):

Well perhaps you are giving string_to_array the incorrect parameters. As alternative you can use the POSITION function to find if there is a sbustring match.

```
with table_a (acol) as ( values('000;111;222'),('000;xxx;222') )
   , table_b (bcol) as ( values ('111'),('xxx'),('000'),('123') )
select * 
  from table_a
  join table_b on POSITION(bcol in acol) > 0;
```